# How to trigger a function from another component's onclick event

Tags: reactjs

So I'm new in ReactJS and there's a cool company offering a junior react developer position if I solve their test project correctly. In the project, I have to draw four svg components and handle some simple events with only one user interaction which is a button click event. So everything seems quite simple but the thing is, I'm stucked in the middle of the project.

I want to give a shake animation to one of the components with a click event in the button component. When Button is clicked, the Tree should shake for 3 seconds and one other action will be triggered after that. I prepared a css animation and I want to change the class of the Tree component every time when the Button component clicked. Could not find out how to do so.

So here is my button component

```
class ShakeButton extends React.Component {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.activeClass==='shake')

    render() {
        return (
            <g id="shakeButton" transform="scale(0.15,0.15), translate(3000,-1000)"  onClick={this.handleClick}>
                //a good amount of svg content here
            </g>
        )
    }
}

export default ShakeButton
```

and here my Tree component (which is gonna change its class name for css animation)

```
import React, { Components } from "react";
import  "./cssTree.css";

class AppleTree extends React.Component{
//   state = {
//     activeClass: ''
//   } n
// handleClick = () => this.props.onClick(this.props.activeClass==='shake')

  render() {
    return (
      <g className="" id="appleTree" >
        <g transform="translate(-1000 -1300) scale(1.5)">
         //again, some crowded svg content here
        </g>
      </g>
    )
  }
}

export default AppleTree
```

I collect all of my components in a component named `<Canvas />` and render it inside the App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try lift the [onClick method and state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), meaning get it in your parent component (`App` I suppose), then pass it down to child components.

```
class App extends React.Component{  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state({
      className: ''
    });
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ className: 'shake' });
  }

  render (
    return (
    // all your components
    <Button clickHandler={this.handleClick} />
    <AppleTree class={this.state.className} />
    )
  )
}

// Button component: Stateless if it doesn't need it's own state
const Button = ({ clickHandler }) => {
 return (
   <g id="shakeButton" transform="scale(0.15,0.15), translate(3000,-1000)"  onClick={() => clickHandler()}>
   //a good amount of svg content here
   </g>
 )
}

// Stateless if it doesn't need its own state
const AppleTree = ({ class }) => {
    return (
      <g className={class} id="appleTree" >
        <g transform="translate(-1000 -1300) scale(1.5)">
         //again, some crowded svg content here
        </g>
      </g>
    )
}
```